# How to print first line of the response and status code in curl

Tags: linux, bash, curl

```
curl -o /dev/null -s -w "HTTPCode=%{http_code}_TotalTime%{time_total}s\n" http://test.com
```

just gives me the status code

I also want the body of the response, How can i do that in the command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't send it to /dev/null? `-o` is throwing it away.

```
curl -sw "HTTPCode=%{http_code}_TotalTime%{time_total}s\n" http://test.com
```

If you ONLY want the first line, as your title suggests, filter it.

```
curl -sw "HTTPCode=%{http_code}_TotalTime%{time_total}s\n" http://test.com | sed -n '1p; $p;'
```

This tells sed to print the *first* and *last* lines, because you asked for the first one, and `-w` prints after completetion. My test:

```
$: curl -s -w "HTTPCode=%{http_code}_TotalTime%{time_total}s\n" google.com | sed -n '1p; $p;'
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
HTTPCode=301_TotalTime0.270267s
```

If you specifically mean the first line of the *body* from the response, now you need to define "first line" a little, and you should really get an HTML-aware parser. I *could* probably do it in `sed`, but it's really kind of a bad idea in most cases.

If that's really what you need, let me know, supply some additional details, and we'll work on it.

## edit

OP requested the lines be in the reverse order, so I offered this:

```
$: curl -s -w "HTTPCode=%{http_code}_TotalTime%{time_total}s\n" google.com | sed -n '1h; ${p;x;p;}'
HTTPCode=301_TotalTime0.270267s
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
```

To explain the `sed` -
`sed -n` says `n`o output unless I ask for it.
`1h;` says on line 1, `h`old the data in the pattern buffer (the line just read, since we haven't edited it) in the "hold" buffer.
`${` says on the *last* line, open a set of commands to execute, which will be closed with the matching `}` close brace.
`p;x;p;` -

- `p` means `p`rint the current pattern buffer, which on the last line will be the last line just read in.
- `x` means e`x`change the hold and pattern buffers. This puts line 1, still in the `h`old buffer, into the standard pattern buffer space.
- `p` again `p`rints the *new* value of the pattern buffer, which is the held line 1.

Comment: How can I print the status code first and the output next, right now the output is coming first and status code is coming second

Comment: I am doing this : curl -s  -w "HTTPCode=%{http_code}_TotalTime%{time_total}s\n" http://test.com | pandoc -f html -t plain | sed -n '$p; 1p;'

Comment: for the sed, try `sed -n '1h; ${p;x;p;}'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `curl + awk` solution:

```bash
curl -sw "HTTPCode=%{http_code}_TotalTime%{time_total}s\n" 'http://test.com' |
awk '{p=p $0 ORS} END{print; sub(/\n[^\n]+\n$/, "", p); print p}'
```